# Error: singular matrix 'a' in solve for categorical variables as fixed effects in bife-package in R

Tags: logistic, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am estimating a panel logit model, which looks like this:

$logit(P(event_it = 1)) = β₀ + β₁X_{i,t-1} + µ₁Z_i + α_i + ε_{i,t}$

where:

$P(event_it = 1)$ represents the probability of a flood occurring for catchment i in month t.

$X_{i,t-1}$ represents the independent variables for catchment i at time t-1, specifically Prec_it-1, SM_it-1, and GW_it-1, which are binary dummy variables indicating drought anomalies in catchment i in month t-1.

$Z_i$ represents the time-invariant variables for catchment i, such as climate type and soil type for catchment i.

$α_i$ represents the unobserved individual-specific fixed effects.

$ε_{i,t}$ is the error term.

I want to use the bias-corrected logit (BCL) estimator, hence the R-package 'bife', since I also want coeffecients for my control variables/fixed effects, especially climate types (since I want to answer the question how the relation between flood occurrence and antecedent drought-indicators differs between climate types).

I use the following code

```
formula <- flood ~ 
  prec_dummy_1 + prec_dummy_2 + prec_dummy_3 + prec_dummy_4 + prec_dummy_5 +
  sm_root_dummy_1 + sm_root_dummy_2 + sm_root_dummy_3 + sm_root_dummy_4 + sm_root_dummy_5 +
  sm_surf_dummy_1 + sm_surf_dummy_2 + sm_surf_dummy_3 + sm_surf_dummy_4 + sm_surf_dummy_5 +
  gw_dummy_1 + gw_dummy_2 + gw_dummy_3 + gw_dummy_4 + gw_dummy_5 +
  ndvi_dummy_1 + ndvi_dummy_2 + ndvi_dummy_3 + ndvi_dummy_4 + ndvi_dummy_5 +
  flow_dummy_1 + flow_dummy_2 + flow_dummy_3 + flow_dummy_4 + flow_dummy_5  +
  climate.type + landcover.type + soil.type + lithology.type + area + ele.mean + ele.max + slp.mean| catchment_id 


model_hydr_DF_BCL <- bife(formula, 
                          data = df_hydr, 
                          model = "logit")


summary(model_hydr_DF_BCL)
```

I get the error

```
Error in qr.solve(MX, nu * w_tilde, epsilon) : 
  singular matrix 'a' in solve
```

Though I only get this error when including categorical variables:climate.type + landcover.type + soil.type + lithology.type. There is no problem with controlling for area + ele.mean + ele.max + slp.mean.

Can somebody help me please?